# Knockout JS - Function is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am getting the error 'TabsViewModel is not a constructor' with the following code. I've looked at other posts regarding this error, but most suggest that the function name is in use somewhere else, but as you can see this is a very simple example and TabsViewModel is not used elsewhere.

```js
        define(['utils','ko','text!tmpl/risersandfallerstabs_partial.html','text!tmpl/errorPage_partial.html'], function(utils,ko,tmplrisersandfallerstabsStr,tmplErrStr) {
let tabsmodel = {}; 
$(function() {           
    tabsmodel = new TabsViewModel();
    ko.components.register('risersandfallerstabs', {
        viewModel: utils.createVM(tabsmodel), 
        template: tmplrisersandfallerstabsStr                      
    });
    utils.applyBindings(tabsmodel,'risersandfallerstabs');

    var TabsViewModel = (function(){
        let self = {};
        self.test = "123";
        return self;
    });
});
})
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to call TabsViewModel before it exists. Move your function definition above the function execution.

```
  var TabsViewModel = (function() {
    let self = {};
    self.test = "123";
    return self;
  });

  tabsmodel = new TabsViewModel();
```

Answer (score 1):

I was running into a similar issue, the problem was that my class was an anonymous function instead of a normal function.

Didn't work:

```
var TabsViewModel = () => { ... }
```

Worked:

```
var TabsViewModel = function() { ... }
```